# Meteor with Angular 2 - how to use node libraries like fs and others?

Tags: meteor, typescript, angular, angular2-meteor

all !

Basic question : In many previous app, I'm used to do in this way:

```
const fs = require('fs');
```

this does not work as well...

```
var fs = Npm.require('fs');
```

Now...using angular 2 with meteor and typescript I've no clue how to produce the same line of code.

Any solution ? Actually I just need to load a json file from my File System, but in the future I will need to use many others libs like S3 (amazon) and others.

ty !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using Meteor version **1.3**? If so, please take a look at [this](http://guide.meteor.com/using-npm-packages.html) section of the Meteor guide. Meteor 1.3 uses ES2015 module syntax with the `import` and `export` keywords. You can learn more about this syntax [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

In your case, you should be able to import and use the **fs** npm package in your Meteor apps as so:

```
import fs from 'fs'
```

Then that variable is available for you to use through that file.

Of course, this is assuming you've first installed and saved the npm package to your project via `meteor npm install <package-name> --save`

I am not sure if you have used it before but [this](http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/bootstrapping) Angular2-Meteor tutorial should come handy as well.